# Retrieving Data from MySQL With Partial Data

Tags: java, mysql

Currently, I use a search field in JAVA to obtain information about an employee using a MySQL search as outlined below:

```
String sql = "select * from CISData where NAME = ?";

        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, searchPeopleField.getText());
        rs=pst.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next()) {
            String add1 = rs.getString("MONTHYEAR");
            ymField.setText(add1);
            String add2 = rs.getString("NAME");
            nameField.setText(add2);
            String add3 = rs.getString("REFERENCENO");
            ernField.setText(add3);
            String add4 = rs.getString("UTR");
            utrField.setText(add4);
            String add5 = rs.getString("VERIFICATIONNO");
            vrField.setText(add5);
            String add6 = rs.getString("MONTHENDING");
            meField.setText(add6);
            String add7 = rs.getString("GAP");
            gapField.setText(add7);
            String add8 = rs.getString("LCM");
            lcmField.setText(add8);
            String add9 = rs.getString("ALD");
            aldField.setText(add9);
            String add10 = rs.getString("AD");
            adField.setText(add10);
            String add11 = rs.getString("AP");
            apField.setText(add11);    
        }
```

As you can see from the above SQL statement, I select the data appropriate to the correct employee using their name which is saved under the 'NAME' column in a MySQL database.

The field 'NAME' in the MySQL database table contains their full name, for example, 'John Doe'.  Now the problem with this approach, is that it only retrieves the information when I type the full name in, for example, 'John Doe'.

Now, my question is, is it possible to somehow suggest the full name to me when I type in 'Joh' instead of actually typing in their full name - 'John Doe'?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to use `LIKE` in your `sql` query.

```
String name = searchPeopleField.getText();//Joh
String sql = 'select * from CISData where NAME LIKE' +name+'%';
```

Comment: It seems to not like the fact that I have used the percentage sign at the end and throws an error about the compatibility with the MySQL server.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`LIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html) query (`WHERE NAME LIKE 'Joh%'`), count results and if more than one, "suggest"

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of AJAX call for this requirement.